# Use a map with <Type, InstanceOfType> in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I want to create a Map that has a classtype as a key and an instance of that class as a value.

Thus far, I have been able to generate this:

```
export interface RequestState
{
 new(): PrimaryState<RequestData>;
}

//create a new map that uses classtype as the key and instance as the value.
private states: Map<RequestState, PrimaryState<RequestData>> = new Map<RequestState, PrimaryState<RequestData>>();

//set a new instance of the state_requestRoom class.
this.states.set(state_requestRoom, new state_requestRoom());
```

which all works fine, however, now I want to be able to get that instance as a generic type:

```
public activateState<T extends RequestState>(): T
{
    const state: PrimaryState<RequestData> = this.states.get(T);
    return state;
}
```

but that gives me the error **'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)**
I could pass the argument as a parameter, but than I can only return the instance as a PrimaryState, as far as I know. I would like to do the following:

```
const requestRoomState: state_requestRoom = stateHandler.activateState<state_requestRoom>();
```

Comment: Your function needs an argument. You want to pass the key of the map (state_requestRoom for example) in order to get the corresponding value. And it doesn't need to be generic. So it should be called using `const requestRoomState: state_requestRoom = stateHandler.activateState(state_requestRoom);`

Comment: hi JB, thanks for your answer! I'm afraid that it doesn't really work however, because it can't be assigned to requestRoomState, as it is returned as an instance of PrimaryState. Only when I add - ```requestRoomState: state_requestRoom = stateHandler.activateState(state_requestRoom) as state_requestRoom;``` does it work.

Comment: Yes, you need that type assertion, indeed. The core part of my comment is that you need an argument for your method. Generic types don't exist at runtime. You can't pass the generic type T to Map.get().

Comment: ok, I was hoping I could surpass that assertion but if there is no other way then I'll just add it. Thanks again!

Comment: There could be a way. I'm not an expert. I just know that your method needs an argument, and can't just use T as argument to Map.get().